Magnetic lines geometry inside a dc motor
How are the magnetic lines of the armature and stator field distributed? Are they always perpendicular to each other or do they align in every half cycle (while the rotor is rotating)? I suppose that for the laplace force to be applied the correct way the current in the armature's coil has to be perpendicular to the magnetic field of the stator, and so its magnetic field has to align with it in every half cycle.

In a production DC motor as you suggest the magnetic fields are perpendicular to each other in order to maximize the torque produced by the motor.
They are kept this way during the rotation of the motor by the commutator. This is a multi segment conducting contact built onto the rotor shaft. It is fed by fixed brushes. As the shaft rotates different segments connect to the brushes and feed different coils. These coils are used in combination to keep the magnetic field close to perpendicular to the stator field.


They are not perfectly perpendicular, though, as that would require a commutator with infinite segments.

@Hearth note the words "close to".

Your first paragraph just says "are perpendicular", though.
